# Face recognition with dl4j

Tags: apache-spark, face-recognition, dl4j

I am working on a project for face recognition with photos taken by cameras. I should use a virtual machine with spark and deeplearning4j.
The problem is that I didn't find the suitable algorithm and code to use for creating the neural network.

What is the difference between VGG16, keras, dataVec? and when we should use those models?

Answer (score 0):

All the things you asked can be found through just a google search still giving you links just to give you a direction
[VGG16](https://gist.github.com/baraldilorenzo/07d7802847aaad0a35d3)

[Keras](https://keras.io/)